# how to tell excel to begin formular e.g. from third column

Tags: excel

I have a set of data for budget, e.g. when a new employee is starting but they will start from June I want excel to match the header June then do the calculation in June column,

I can run the formula (match) and it returns value 3 for June i.e. 3rd column how do i get excel to actually start the formula from 3rd column and black the first 2?

The ones in circle should be '0' and the formula should only work from June onwards

***Screenshot***
[image]

Comment: `If(header_date < employee_start_date, 0, formula)`?

Comment: W.R.T. blacking the cells you can't change the format from inside an excel function without some really dirty VBA work-arounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An if statement helps you here 
=if(G$2>= Field of Start Date, EXECUTE FORMULA, 0)

Use today() in any cell to check which date format you are currently using & adapt the date in the Field of Start Date afterwards.

Comment: I have something like this =IF(INDEX($E$5:$P$5,MATCH(C21,$E$5:$P$5,0))=C21,$E$16*$D$21,"") however if I drag this across it won't work